# If $X_1,X_2 \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ , then find $E[(X_1+X_2)^2|X_1=X_2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

If $X_1,X_2 \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ , then find $E[(X_1+X_2)^2|X_1=X_2]$
It seems to me that the expectation will be $4 \mu^2$ but I am going wrong somewhere.
How to tackle these types of problems where the condition given is a linear restriction on $X_1,X_2$?

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ assumed independent?

Comment: No nothing is mentioned

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $\mathsf{P}(X_1=X_2)=0$...

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes, and? (Note that the fact that the OP seems basically unable to understand / address your objection is problematic, yes, but not the objection itself.)

Comment: "How to tackle these types of problems where the condition given is..." The first step would be to recall how $E(U\mid V=v)$ is defined in full generality. Can you?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement "It seems to me that the expectation will be $4\mu^2$ but I am going wrong somewhere" ? Otherwise this post is being voted to close due to lack of context/effort.

Answer (score 3):

The expression $E\,[(X+Y)^2\mid X=Y]$ is ambiguous, as user @Did justifies below.

I am treating it as $E\,[(X+Y)^2\mid X-Y=0]$ in my answer.

Assume that $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal with mean vector $(\mu,\mu)^T$ and dispersion matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2 & \rho\sigma^2 \\ \rho\sigma^2 & \sigma^2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Define $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$, so that $(U,V)$ is also jointly normal with mean vector $(2\mu,0)^T$ and dispersion matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2\sigma^2(1+\rho) & 0\\0 & 2\sigma^2(1-\rho) \end{bmatrix}$. As $\operatorname{cov}(U,V)$ vanishes, $U$ and $V$ are independently distributed.

Hence, $$E\,[(X+Y)^2\mid X-Y=0]=E\,[U^2\mid V=0]=E\,[U^2]=2\sigma^2(1+\rho)+4\mu^2$$

Comment: (+1) for everything in your post except the step $E[(X+Y)^2\mid X=Y]=E(U^2\mid V=0)$, which happens to be problematic, due to an ambiguity in the notations used to state the problem. Are we supposed to understand that $E(Z\mid X=Y)$ is $u(0)$ where $u(X-Y)=E(Z\mid X-Y)$? Or $v(0)$ where $v(X^3-Y^3)=E(Z\mid X^3-Y^3)$? Or $w(0)$ where $w(\arctan X-\arctan Y)=E(Z\mid \arctan X-\arctan Y)$? Or any one from a number of non equivalent suggestions? To sum up, $E(Z\mid T)$ and  $E(Z\mid T=0)$, for some random variable $T$, are well defined, but $E(Z\mid g(T)=h(T))$ is ambiguous.

Comment: @Did I'll admit I did not consider that. Is the problem solved if the question is $E((X+Y)^2\mid X-Y=0)$ instead?

Comment: Definitely. $ $

Comment: @StubbornAtom In the dispersion matrix of $(U,V)$, shouldn't the variance terms be $2\sigma^{2}(1+\rho)$ and $2\sigma^{2}(1-\rho)$ respectively?

Comment: @user46697 Yes, thank you.